# How to fit elements in 100% width without absolute positioning?

Tags: html, layout, css-position, css

I'm trying to do a 4-frame design with css, as in this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/7qBKJ/1/

But I don't want to use `position:absolute;`, and I'm trying to do it like this:

```
topframe: block;
left,right and centerframes: inline-block;
```

And I want to ensure there is, say, 200px of width in both rightframe and leftframe, and the remaining parts should be filled by centerframe. How can I manage this without absolute positioning?

I tried this, but it moves the frames up and down, when the screen width decreases :

http://jsfiddle.net/V4vAc/2/

in this fiddle, `centerframe` aligns with `leftframe`, since they are both `inline-block`, with centerframe rule `margin-left:0px;` but I have no idea how to set `centerframe`'s right to align with `rightframe`'s left, without specifying a width.

So how can I make `#centerframe`'s width equal to screen width - 400 px ?

Thanks !

Comment: I think that if you try to add 'display:block;' and remove 'position:absolut;' it will work...

Comment: Oh I forgot to update the links, please check the second fiddle, with decresing the output window's width.

Comment: This is what are you looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/V4vAc/3/

Comment: @NaveTseva using percentages is a good idea but I was preventing that since I'm afraid that in some small screens, they could be less than 200px. I need this certain amount of width since I will put fixed size ads on the left and rightframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is to put both sidebars first in the flow of the document.  Then you float the first sidebar right and the second one left.

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="center"></div>

/* main.css */
#left {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
}
#right {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    float: right;
}
#center {
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samgh/JjsFF/

If you want `center` to be the full width underneath the two sidebars, you can remove the margins.  Hope this helps.